# function return of python

Tags: python, function, return

I am reading John Zelle's Python programming 2ed Ch6. And I encounter a concept question:
His example code says:

```
#addinterest3.py 
def addInterest(balances, rate):
    for i in range(len(balances)):
        balances[i] * (1 + rate)


def test():
    amounts = [1000, 2200, 800, 360]
    rate = 0.05
    addInterest(amounts, rate)
    print(amounts)


test()
```

with upper code the

> "assignments into the list caused it to refer to the new values. The old values will actually 
>   get cleaned up when Python does garbage collection"

According to this idea I tried a test.py

```
def add(balance, rate):
    balance = balance * (1 + rate)


def test():
    amount = 1000
    rate = 0.5
    amount = add(amount, rate)
    print(amount)


test()
```

I think the balance can also be assigned by a new values, but it turns out return "none" in my terminal. Can anyone explain what is the fundamental difference between them? 
Why list assignment dont need to use return to pass the value but will still be saved, on the other hand, my test.py do required a "return balance" after the function ?

Comment: is that your actual code? cause the indentation is completely wrong.

Comment: The code in `addInterest` has no side effects and no explicit return value. Specifically, `balances[i]*(1+rate)` does not modify any value. Given the code above, this is not correct: "assignments into the list caused it to referto the new values." There are no assignments into the list. That would require `balances[i] *= (1+rate)`

Comment: I just copy what is on the book.

Comment: See also: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not getting any value in `amount` is because your `add` function is not returning anything.

```
def add(balance,rate):
    return balance*(1+rate)
```

Would return a value which would be assigned to `amount`.

Added to that, the beginning code is wrong. If you we're to try this code in python you would find that it prints out:

```
[1000, 2200, 800, 360]
```

it needs to be changed to:

```
def addInterest(balances,rate):
    for i in range(len(balances)):
        balances[i] = balances[i]*(1+rate)
```

Comment: I think my problem is why if the parameters in function have to be passed by value but if the variable is a list then you will find out your "object change" become "visible" in your result.(Sorry i am a novice and not good at english yet this problem really confuses me)

Comment: Python does not pass every parameter as a reference, only lists and the like. So even if you did `add(amount, rate)` the `amount` will not change. Appart from that, you cant assign `amount` to the return of a non-returning function, it will just put in a `None`. If the code in your question was in that book, **Do not use that book** learn from [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/)

Answer (score 1):

As I may expect, if you pass a list as a function argument it like you pass the pointer on this list. Assignment statements in Python do not copy objects, they create bindings between a target and an object. Therefore if you change the list inside the function you can see these changes. If you pass the variables, the copies of these variables are used inside the function.
As an example you can also try this code:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = a
a.append(3)
print a, b
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
```

Ups!

Answer (score 0):

Your `add` function doesn't `return` anything, so Python automatically has it return `None` at the end. When you write:

```
amount = add(amount,rate)
```

`add` returns `None`, so `amount` is set to `None`.

Also, not all objects in Python are mutable, so modifying the variable from inside of the function won't do what you expect. Use `return` instead:

```
def add(balance,rate):
    return balance * (1 + rate)
```